# How to get last id insertion with MySQL

Tags: mysql, sql, scala, playframework-2.0, slick

I try to insert 2 rows in database, second row needing auto increment id of first row.
I've test with `LAST_INSERT_ID()` but I have a `MysqlIntegrityConstraintViolationException` :

`Cannot add or update a child row : a foreign key constraint fails ('customer_user_role', CONSTRAINT 'fk_customer_user_role_customer_id' FOREIGN KEY ('customer_user_role_id') REFERENCES 'customer' ('customer_id') ON DELETE NO ACTION ON UPDATE NO ACTION)`

My SQL request are :

`sqlu"INSERT INTO customer (name, email, phone, isActivated) VALUES ($name, $email, $phoneNumber, $isActivated)"`

`sqlu"INSERT INTO customer_user_role (customer_id, user_id, customer_roletype_id) VALUES (LAST_INSERT_ID(), $userId, $roleTypeId)"`

(I work width Play & Slick so that's why particular syntax)

When I execute this on PhpMyAdmin it show me the same error, I don't know how to proceed...

Answer (score 0):

take a look to this http://dev.mysql.com/doc/refman/5.0/en/getting-unique-id.html. before inserting the second row, get the id and proceed. shouldn't be hard.

Comment: I've already seen this doc, and it makes me an error, with `last_insert_id()` and `mysql_insert_id()`

Comment: did you debug? first debug see if you actually getting the value. Is your column is set to Auto Increment?

Comment: When I execute from PHPMyAdmin, it returns me 0... After an insertion of course.

Comment: paste your quires and table structures here, I will fix it for you. the version your running in phpmyadmin.

Comment: I've found my problem, it was just a `;` missing... And for slick each queries must have `.first` at the end to be executed. Thank you anyway !

Answer (score 0):

Try this:

```
     set @last_inserted_id = LAST_INSERT_ID();
```

Then use the @last_inserted_id as a value while inserting into another table.